# Save variable from function into model with python and django

Tags: python, django, telegram-bot

I have created a model and imported it in my views.py file:

```
from app.models import User
```

Next I am receiving a message from a user on telegram:

```
def get_message_from_request(request):

    received_message = {}
    decoded_request = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

    if 'message' in decoded_request:
        received_message = decoded_request['message'] 
        received_message['chat_id'] = received_message['from']['id'] 

    return received_message

class tbotview(generic.View):

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return generic.View.dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        TELEGRAM_TOKEN = ''
        message = get_message_from_request(request)
        send_messages(message, TELEGRAM_TOKEN)

        return HttpResponse()
```

What I would like to do is to save the `id` of the user in my sqlite database. Kind of:

```
u = User(userid='id')
u.save()
```

So right now I am just saving the string `id` obviously. My question is how can I access the `id` from the `received_message` and save this one in my database. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You mean user id from Telegram?

Comment: Yes, exactly!  the user id from Telegram is what I want to save.